# Repetition in obtaining data

Tags: android, android-studio, jsoup

- Hi, I'm trying to get the data from the next page: [Page](https://lectortmo.com/library/manhwa/41512/solo-leveling).. I want to load in my RecyclerView the chapter number (in this case there are 121 chapters) and the url. But, I haven't been able to get it all right.

This is the code for the Body of the page when searching (I simplified it so that only the li from chapter 120 is visible but there is more li below that):

```
<li class="list-group-item p-0 bg-light upload-link" data-index="0">
<h4 class="px-2 py-3 m-0">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-10 text-truncate">
<a style="display: block;" class="btn-collapse" onclick="collapseChapter('collapsible490362')" role="button"> Capítulo 120.00</a>
</div>
</div>
</h4>
<div style="display: block;" id="collapsible490362">
<hr class="mx-0 my-1">
<div class="card chapter-list-element">
 <ul class="list-group list-group-flush chapter-list">
<li class="list-group-item">
<div class="row"><div class="col-2 col-sm-1 text-right">
<a href="https://lectortmo.com/view_uploads/599487" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
<span class="fas fa-play fa-2x" style="color:#2957ba"></span>
</a>
</div>
</div>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</li>
```

The data I want is the chapter number:

```
Capítulo 120.00
Capítulo 119.00
etc
```

And this is how I am parsing the data:

```
@Override
        protected ArrayList<TMODatosSeleccion> doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            String url = getIntent().getStringExtra("valor");

            tmoDatosSeleccions.clear();
            try {
                Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();

                Elements data = doc.select("div.row>.col-10.text-truncate");
                Elements dataDos = doc.select("div.col-2.col-sm-1.text-right");
                for (Element e1 : data) {
                    String numeroCap = e1.select("a").html();
                    numeroCap = numeroCap.replaceAll("\\<.*?\\>", "").trim();
                    for(Element e2 : dataDos){
                        String urlManga = e2.select("a").attr("href");
                        tmoDatosSeleccions.add(new TMODatosSeleccion(numeroCap, urlManga));
                    }
                }
            }  catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return tmoDatosSeleccions;
        }
```

Could someone tell me how I can do it correctly? Since when viewing the data in the `TextView` it looks like this:

[image]

Always see **Caítulo 120.00**

Comment: `data` contains 122 elements, `dataDos` contains 227 elements. Then you have a loop inside a loop so it will iterate 122*227=27694 times. That's probably not what you expect.

Comment: Yes, but what's your solution? Cause to this method i can receive the url correct but if change my code the url to chapter is the same to my 122 elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is:

```
Elements data = doc.select("li.list-group-item.p-0.bg-light.upload-link");
                Log.d("items", "total: " + data.size());
                for (Element e1 : data) {
                    String numeroCap = "";
                    String urlMan = "";
                    if(e1.select("div.col-10.text-truncate").size() > 0){
                        numeroCap = e1.select("a").get(0).text();
                        numeroCap = numeroCap.replaceAll("\\<.*?\\>", "").trim();
                        if(e1.select("div.col-2.col-sm-1.text-right").size() > 0 ){
                            urlMan = e1.select("a.btn.btn-default.btn-sm").get(0).attr("href");
                            if(urlMan.contains("/paginated")){
                                urlMan.replace("/paginated", "/cascade");
                                tmoDatosSeleccions.add(new TMODatosSeleccion(numeroCap, urlMan));
                            }else{
                                tmoDatosSeleccions.add(new TMODatosSeleccion(numeroCap, urlMan));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```